# How to set a property in class from a derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I am not sure how this functions in `C#`.

I have a class:

```
public class FindIt()
{
}

public class FindItFrm()
{
  private bool _amISet = false; 

  public FindItFrm()
  {
  }

  public bool AmISet()
  {
      get { return _amISet; }
  set { _amISet = value; }
  }
}
```

And the class that I am working in has:

```
public class MyHelper() : FindIt
{
    // Constructor
           public MyHelper()
            : base(new FindItFrm())
}
```

I want to set a property (`AmISet`) in the `FindItFrm` while inside the `MyHelper` class.  How would I accomplish this?

Comment: If you want your question answered.. it helps to include the language tag.

Comment: that code doesn't even compile. MyHelper doesn't inherit from anything, which makes it implicitly inherit from `System.Object`

Comment: Remove () in AmISet() as well

Comment: Ok, I see 3 completely disconnected classes. May be you missed some relations between them?

Comment: I am trying to mock up a simple version of the code that I am looking at.  MyHelper would inherit from FindIt() class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this (in the future, please post working code for examples):

```
public class FindIt
{
    // You need to let your derived class access the FindItFrm
    protected FindItFrm Frm;

    // Constructor needs to accept a FindItFrm
    public FindIt(FindItFrm frm)
    {
        Frm = frm;
    }
}

public class FindItFrm
{
    private bool _amISet = false; 

    public bool AmISet
    {
        get { return _amISet; }
        set { _amISet = value; }
    }
}

public class MyHelper : FindIt
{
    // Constructor
    public MyHelper()
        : base(new FindItFrm())
    {
        Frm.AmISet = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I understand how to accomplish this, however it's not as easy to implement in my existing code base.